# The edit: proposed by an anonymous user

Tags: support, editing

I've just rejected an edit on the answer that was made by some anonymous user. **Anonymous user?** Who have the right to make an edit and not even be logged in? Am I right that rejected it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got it now.

[image]

Just wondering why not registered users are allowed to make the changes...

Comment: "We continue to be great admirers of Wikipedia, but we’ve always missed out on one crucial aspect of their system: we never allowed anonymous users to edit content.... Well, as of today, I’m proud to announce that we allow anonymous and new users to edit content in our system! The surface area of this change is huge — it means the millions of drive-by anonymous users that visit our sites every day can submit an improvement or correction." - the [Stack Exchange Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/)

Answer (score 4):

Anyone can propose edits, but if you have less that [1000 reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit)* you need a moderator to approve the edit, to prevent spam and what not.

In this case I don't agree, the edit looks like it improves the answer. Just because it is an anonymous user does not make it wrong.

Stranger still it looks like the edit has been approved anyway

*Once the site leaves beta this number will change to 2000

Comment: But WHO is anonymous user?

Comment: @mast0r  Is that relevant ? Not everyone is interested in credit for their contributions. Or someone could have been logged out without realizing so.

Comment: +1 the edit was constructive and improved the answer quite a bit. Rejecting due to anonymous is very against the spirit of the site.